# Insert Date and time in textbox when button is clicked

Tags: javascript

I am creating something that would generally enter the date and time in the textbox. How can I format the date and time that will only display MM/DD/YYYY ##:##:## inside the textbox. I would like it simple and can be run to IE of any version.

Here is my code:

```
<form>
    <input name="StartDate" size="50"> 
    <input onclick="this.form.StartDate.value = new Date();" type="button" value="Start date"> 
    <input name="StopDate" size="50"> 
    <input onclick="this.form.StopDate.value = new Date();" type="button" value="Stop date">
</form>
```

Comment: Can you paste what code you have already.

Comment: here you go.... <form>

 <input name="StartDate" size="50">

 <input type="button" value="Start date" onclick="this.form.StartDate.value = new Date();">

 <input name="StopDate" size="50">

 <input type="button" value="Stop date" onclick="this.form.StopDate.value = new Date();">


</form>

Comment: You need to edit your question and add the code there.

Comment: Thanks Theo and Ashley here is my code <form>

 <input name="StartDate" size="50">

 <input type="button" value="Start date" onclick="this.form.StartDate.value = new Date();">

 <input name="StopDate" size="50">

 <input type="button" value="Stop date" onclick="this.form.StopDate.value = new Date();">


</form>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use getMonth, getYear methods etc. on a date object - this should be supported in older versions of IE.

```
var myDate = new Date();
this.form.StopDate.value = (myDate.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + myDate.getDate() + "/" + myDate.getFullYear()+ ' ' + myDate.getHours() + ":" + myDate.getMinutes() + ":" + myDate.getSeconds();
```

See [Docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff743760(v=vs.94).aspx)

It may makes sense to define this as a function:

```
function getDateString(){
    var myDate = new Date();
    return (myDate.getMonth() + 1) + 
        "/" + myDate.getDate() + 
        "/" + myDate.getFullYear() + 
        ' ' + myDate.getHours() + 
        ":" + myDate.getMinutes() + 
        ":" + myDate.getSeconds();
}
```

And then use in your button:
`<input onclick="this.form.StartDate.value = getDateString();" type="button" value="Start date">`

You may also need to handle adding leading 0's to your date, this snippet takes care of this:

```js
function getDateString(){
    var myDate = new Date();
    return padDatePart(myDate.getMonth() + 1) + 
        "/" + padDatePart(myDate.getDate()) + 
        "/" + myDate.getFullYear()+ 
        ' ' + padDatePart(myDate.getHours()) + 
        ":" + padDatePart(myDate.getMinutes()) + 
        ":" + padDatePart(myDate.getSeconds());
}

function padDatePart(part){
    return ('0'+part).slice(-2); 
}
```

```html
<form>
    <input name="StartDate" size="50"> 
    <input onclick="this.form.StartDate.value = getDateString();" type="button" value="Start date"> 
    <input name="StopDate" size="50"> 
    <input onclick="this.form.StopDate.value =getDateString();" type="button" value="Stop date">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks Theo, appreciate the code but not that good with javascript.. just have basic knowledge with the coding... I dont know where to insert this code. If you can give me more specific details where to add this code. this will help me a lot to really understand every code.

Comment: I have updated my answer, the functions would need placing inside a `<script>` tag.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot man... It worked. I still have few question but i will save that in the future... I am still doing some coding and if I will not work.I will definitely asking it in here. Really appreciate you help. Amazing!

Comment: Great - please remember to accept any answers that solve your problems, it helps others know it is the right answer and rewards the answer with some points